# Why sqlite 3 stopped working on "delete" class calls in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, class

I have the following code structure that does all the things required except removing the line item I am asking to remove. Code does not throw any error, basically the program disregards de "delete" action.

```
    class MainPage():
        def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
            # Coding stuff to build the windows and manage an inventory of items, incl. a button 
            # that allows the user to delete a line item if she/he considers necessary (calling to def below)
        def update_inventory(self, open_web=True, update_trigger=False, sold=False, delete=False):
            # Coding stuff to get what the user wants to manage, including an inventory item to remove
            if delete:
                value_to_remove = str(self.actual_pick[i][0])
                import sqlite3
                with sqlite3.connect("MTGdb.db") as db:
                    cursor = db.cursor()
                    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM db_inventory WHERE id = ?", (value_to_remove,))
                    db.commit()
```

Funny thing is that if I use the Python Console and ask for the exactly same statements but asking for the "value_to_remove" manually (it is an integer, e.g. 8224 id item), it works. So I am starting to think that there is a problem on querying it from a class. Even if I call for this action in a "def" statement out of the class it still does not work.

What does work (meaning, effectively updating the database) is adding a `db.close()` call after the `db.commit()` but throwing a `slite3.ProgrammingError` because it cannot operate on a closed database just in the line I state `db.close()`. Because of that error, the tkinter windows are not updating the changes on the db so this proxy is not acceptable. Note that `except` approaches don't work: e.g.:

```
try:
    db.close()
except sqlite3.ProgrammingError:
    print("I skip the db.close() statement")
```

Still throws me an `sqlite3.ProgrammingError` on the `print` statement.

Important to note that other sqlite3 actions DO work, like UPDATE sqls... so my problem is limited to the "DELETE" sqls.

Appreciated if someone can bring me more visibility on the problem and how I can manage it. Thanks!!

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete example. You code is not sufficient to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Sorry, my code is 5.000 lines, but I posted the most relevant ones. I do not think the rest of the lines are meaningful, unless someone explains if this problem may came from certain statements that are problematic. As this issue is isolated with an specific sqlite3 call (delete) that works on a Console but does not work on a class nor a def called from a class, I was wondering that the problem is related to the sqlite calls (e.g. versions?)

Comment: From the available evidence either: (1) the `delete` keyword argument is `False` (the default) (2) `value_to_remove` does not match the value that you expect (3) the hardcoded database name is wrong.  Without a [mre] it's not possible to know for sure.

Comment: @RubenHerencia Try to write a short test case that reproduces the problem. This will often reveal the cause of the problem before you finish writing it.

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro, I did and realized a workaround (but not discovered the source of the problem though). But the thought process was relevant for me.